# Stopping Autocomplete from browers?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

I have implemented my own autocomplete via jQuery but the browser covers up the first option with its own autocomplete info? Is there a way to turn off this field's autocomplete from the server side?

Comment: @OTZ: amusingly, that edit was already made... and then rolled back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
autocomplete="off"
```

in your `INPUT` tag.

Comment: perfect! Knew it had to be simple! Thanks... I'll except once it lets me!

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Possibly because it's an exact duplicate. I've corrected it though.